# If it is possible to track the "text input state" system-wide? How?

Tags: x11, gui, gtk, qt

Is it possible to track that system is currently in "text-input state" := when the window that has text input field (or "text input possibility" to be more general) is open now and the focus is exactly on this field? If it's possible in some "unified manner" (there is some package that gives an API for it) — please mention.

How much info can be extracted with different methods?

As far as I've got the XServer only manages windows and won't give info on this sort of system state by default and that can be done individually using GTK/QT but that will only work respectively for programs that use exact same library... Although I also do know there are some linux phone distributions "PostmarketOS" and etc. (I didn't yet tried any) that got to do some sort of tracking like this in order to know whenever to show virtual keyboard, right?

Comment: That's what I've found for wayland: https://wayland.app/protocols/text-input-unstable-v3#zwp_text_input_v3:event:commit_string